# change html codes using jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, togglebutton

I got a pricing table in which I intend to use toggle button (monthly/yearly)
to toggle price number, link href and time interval text. I just stuck up with no knowledge on how to make it get to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
<select class="segment-select">
  <option value="1">Monthly</option>
  <option value="2">Yearly</option>
</select>
<div class="content1">
    $<span class="price">25<!-- show 250 when toggled!--></span> 
    <span class="interval">monthly <!-- show yearly when toggled!--></span>
    <a href="link1<!-- link1-alt when toggled!-->">Sign up</a>
</div>
<div class="content2">
    $<span class="price">45<!-- show 450 when toggled!--></span> 
    <span class="interval">monthly <!-- show yearly when toggled!--></span>
    <a href="link2<!-- link2-alt when toggled!-->">Sign up</a>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ttsqqcoy/

Comment: Have you read up on the jQuery UI library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, how this could be done (changes made on your original code):

**HTML:**

```
<div class='contentTable'>
  <div class="content">
      <span class="price"></span> 
      <span class="interval"></span>
      <a class='link' href="#">Sign Up</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <span class="price"></span>
      <span class="interval"></span>
      <a class='link' href="#">Sign Up</a>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".segment-select").Segment();

var options = {
    monthly: [
        {price: 25, link: 'link1'},
        {price: 45, link: 'link2'},
    ],
    yearly: [
        {price: 300, link: 'link3'},
        {price: 540, link: 'link4'},
    ]
}

function fillContent(interval) {
    var data = options[interval];

    $('.content').each(function(index) {
        var content = $(this);

        content.find('.price').text('$' + data[index].price);
        content.find('.interval').text(interval);
        content.find('.link').attr('href', data[index].link);
    });
}

// initialization 

fillContent("monthly");

$('.ui-segment').on("click", '.option', function() {
    var interval = $(this).attr('value');

    fillContent(interval);
});
```

Here is example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tara5/5kgw964L/

It should solve your problem for this two rows in your table.

However, if you will have more than two rows, or even not constant amount of them, code will become messy and hardly maintainable. (Generally it's bad to hold your data in DOM).

So you should try to use Backbone, for example.

Here is how your problem could be solved with Backbone (jsfiddle link):

http://jsfiddle.net/tara5/2r3t2Lrg/

Also see Backbone docs and examples. (Can't provide them now, can't post more than 2 links =) )

Comment: How to add fade effect { effect: "fadeIn", duration: 500 } to first example?

Comment: I just needed updating the code for alternative switch button http://jsfiddle.net/5kgw964L/7/ I used http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You rocks. Last request, adding class to html span according to selected interval <span class="active">Monthly</span> <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" /> <span class="">Yearly</span>. http://jsfiddle.net/5kgw964L/9/

Answer (score 0):

You should use java script to do this

```
$('.segment-select').change(function(e) {
  if ($(".segment-select option:selected").val() == '1')
  {
    $('.content1').show();
    $('.content2').hide();
  } else {
    $('.content2').show();
    $('.content1').hide();
  }
})
```

If this is what you need?